# How to fetch record id using Salesforce instance URL address

Tags: visualforce

I have VF page and placed that in home side bar component page and I am capturing the Salesforce instance URL from visual force using custom controller.

```
public String getReferer()
{ 
    BrowserURL = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('referer'); 
    return browserURL;
}
```

Now I want to fetch recorded id using Salesforce instance URL in VF page.

How can I get record id using that URL. Eg: 
I am getting Salesforce browser URL like: https://ap1.salesforce.com/0019000000GJMHG 
using this URL How can I get Salesforce record id through controller and display the record id in VF page. Like : Record Id: 0019000000GJMHG Can anyone please help me to overcome this issue?

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that because referer information can violate privacy, some web browsers allow the user to disable the sending of referer information. Don't rely on this referral information as it's possible that it will not be present. If it is critical to know the ID from the previous page, pass it along as a URL parameter in the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can use the string methods now to pull the ID.

```
BrowserURL=BrowserURL.right(15);//Pull from right the 15 digit Id
```

If your org is not update to winter 13 then you can use  `String.Split('/')` and get the last array element value .

Comment: This won't work if there are any get params in the URL, specifically the retURL param will be present on a large number of pages.

Answer (score 6):

I've done this in javascript in the past and it boiled down to two regular expressions:

for the / URL format:

```
/\.com\/\w{15}|\.com\/\w{18}/
```

and for the ?id= format:

```
/id\=\w{15}|id\=\w{18}/
```

It's not foolproof - any VF page can use custom parameter names, but it covers all standard UI pages I'm aware of any any visualforce that uses a StandardController.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is completely foolproof, but seems to be working for me

Example:

```
BrowserURL = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('referer').Split('/')[3].left(15);
```